# docker run command output

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am just learning the basic basic docker commands by setting up in Ubuntu .
By running the following command :

> $sudo docker run -i -t tutum/hello-world /bin/bash

I get the output as :

```
root@1035h04e176:/#
```

I dint understand whats going on here. I thought `$docker run … /bin/bash` will create a new container with the id as the output of the command , can somebody please tell me , has the container already created? If yes how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the `-i`option. It runs the container in "interactive" mode : it attaches the standard input and outputs, and in this case (running `/bin/bash`) you're thus entering the container shell.

If you don't want to attach any input/output stream to your current shell and only get it container ID, run it in "detach" mode:

```
$sudo docker run -d -t tutum/hello-world /bin/bash
4f812a7b4f0e0c681eb3616cb04d0797eda37e32d1e5b35f79dfa686d95b3aee
```